# Determine which one affects the data

Tags: statistics

[image]
How the mean or the range affects the graph of this data ?
I do not know how can i determine the right answer

Comment: Do you know what the marks on a box plot mean? Once you do, this problem becomes pretty easy.

Comment: Do you understand how these plots work? It is not an ordinary graph. It is designed to display certain features of the data. They are known as box plots.The outer ticks are the smallest and larges values. The ends of the box is the interquartile range and the vertical line inside the box is the median.

Comment: A box plot is one way of illustrating the quartiles of a range of data.  Through the process of elimination, you should be able to answer this question.